# Why do I get the Verilog syntax error [HDL 9-806]?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to generate a testbench for a module, but I'm getting a syntax error. Code is:

```verilog
module tb_clock_test;

reg clk, pps_in, rst;
wire pps_rcvd, pps_out;
wire [26:0] count;
int d;


clk_test uut(
    .core_clk(clk),
    .pps_in(pps_in),
    .rst(rst),
    .pps_rcvd(pps_rcvd),
    .pps_out(pps_out),
    .count(count)
);

initial begin
    clk <= 0;
    pps_in <= 0;
    rst <= 1;
    clk = !clk;
    #8 rst = 0;
    clk = !clk;
    #8 rst = 1;
    clk = !clk;
    #8 pps_in = 1;
end

for (d = 0; d < 250000000; d = d + 1) begin
    #8 clk = !clk;
end
end module
```

Why do I get the following error?

> [HDL 9-806] Syntax error near "#". ["tb_clock_test.v":31]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop needs to be inside a procedural block.  One way to fix the error is:

```
initial begin
    for (d = 0; d < 250000000; d = d + 1) begin
        #8 clk = !clk;
    end
end
```

Once you fix that error, you should get another error.  Change the two separate keywords `end module` to the single keyword `endmodule`.